Replacing the crankset on Cannondale CAADX 105 from 2017 (BB30)
I have a problem with Cannondale CAADX 105 from 2017. Chainring wobbles when pedaling, and chain touches the front derailleur. I took it to a LBS, and they told me the problem is in the crank and spindle connection (photos attached). They also said they don't have the parts, but they can replace it if I order them myself.
Original crankset is FSA Gossamer Cross BB30 46/36, but I can't find it anywhere and am looking for alternatives. Can you please recommend what parts should I order, that are currently available in EU? Getting adapters and switching to another standard is also an option, I just want to make sure I order something that fits.
Thank you!



Throw in an shell adapter to BSA and the world is your oyster. https://www.bike24.com/p2158630.html or use a BB30 to alternate standard e.g. DUB bottom bracket https://www.bike24.com/search-result/category-Components%20%3E%20Drive%20%3E%20Bottom%20Brackets?searchTerm=Bb30

The first question is whether replacing it with another 46/36 crank is actually what you want to do. It's pretty useless for anyone not actually racing cross. If this bike has FD-5800 or FD-6800 it will work well enough with 46/30, though on paper they were made for 46/36 and not 46/30. I think this bike has chainstay clearance for 50/34 as well but you'd need to double check.

@WarrenBurton Thank you!

@NathanKnutson No, I'm not racing cross. I'm using the bike for touring and commuting. I will look into other crank sizes. Thank you!

There are several options available to allow a BB30 bottom bracket shell to accept most any standard of crankset.  For any bike having any given bottom bracket standard, the key to knowing what bottom bracket you need (and thus any BB30 conversion BB needed) lies with your choice of crankset.  Specifically, what the chosen crankset's spindle/bottom bracket standard is.  Obviously, one must match the bottom bracket (or conversion BB) to the requirements of the crankset.
In your case, the CAADX frame has a bottom bracket shell of the BB30 standard: a 68mm wide shell with a 42mm internal diameter bore. Any conversion bottom bracket selection must 1) be designed to fit the 68/42mm shell, and 2) be equipped with the appropriate bearings (in terms of internal diameter bore and whether they sit externally or internal to the shell) to fit the selected crankset's spindle diameter and length.
In short, the first step is to select a replacement crankset, then shop for the appropriate BB30 or BB30 conversion bottom bracket to marry with with crankset.
Your CAADX having a Shimano 105, 11 speed groupset, you may be interested in running a Shimano 105 crankset. Shimano Hollowtech2 cranksets utilize a 24mm spindle attached to the right, drive side crankarm. They also are designed for outboard BB bearings (sitting outside the BB shell). The bearings are preloaded with a plastic bolt coming thru the left crankarm and into the spindle. All is secured via 2 pinch bolts on the left crankarm that compress the splined end of the spindle.
At any rate, several manufacturers make BB30 to 24mm Shimano conversion BB's. They differ in their approach to providing the external bearings (24mm internal diameter). One technique is pressed in cups with the external bearings pressed into those.  Because of the propensity of BB30 press fits to creak, some manufacturers have developed thread together bottom brackets where the right and left sides are a portion of a threaded sleeve attached to the press in cup which has the bearing contained that remains outside the BB shell. The portions of the internal shell thread together offering a tight and generally creak free option. See photo below.

There are other crankset manufacturers that have slightly different standards of spindle and require outboard BB bearings. Here is one manufacturer's offering of thread together BBs for the BB30 shell standard.
Another idea is to convert your shell to the threaded BSA standard altogether with an adapter that is press fit into the shell and fixed rather permanently with Loctite 609 green (a thin version of medium strength Loctite used in press fit applications like bearings or bushings). After these are installed and the Loctite cures, you're left with a shell converted to the threaded BSA standard.  Now you can install the variety of BSA threaded bottom brackets, even, say, a cartridge bearing BB with a square taper spindle.

There are other types of BB30 conversion bottom brackets available as well.  I can vouch for the quality of each of the pictured converters. In my case, I had a couple PF30 mountain bikes and prefer Shimano components. While the FSA converter requires the additional purchase of the appropriate BSA bottom bracket, the price point of the thread together Wheels Mfg converter is higher than the combo of BSA converter + appropriate BSA threaded bottom bracket.
In both cases, on heavily used, carbon fiber, Specialized Stumpjumpers, I've not had any issues at the bottom bracket    using these converters with multiple cranksets.m

Shell conversion and "pipe" style conversion BBs don't usually work in the caadx due to frame internal landscape. Check before spending too much money. Standard bearings with wheelsmfg reducers are often the only option.

@Jeff Thank you for the detailed reply. I'm thinking about this BB30 to 24mm Shimano option.

@Noise I'm assuming you mean that the second option described above (FSA adapter to BSA) might not work, but WheelsMFG would be better?

Not sure why the FSA wouldn't work. Check  out the spare parts list for Cannondale CAADX 2019+. Looks identical to the FSA converter. If the 2017 model is clear of obstructions, the pipe style should work

Actually, looking closer at my link above, it IS the FSA adapter pictured in my post. The above link in my comment above is the official Cannondale website and specific to CAADX frames.

My experience is with the 2012-2016 model range. The older models including the first disc models have an obstruction, the shell is raised/thickened where the cable guide bolts in. Also consider later models may even have BB30a, which is offset and 73mm wide.

@Noise I did confirm that the CAADX continues it's design with a 68mm shell  and uses the BB30 and not the BB30a standard. I certainly think the points regarding the pipe style (FSA conversion pictured in my answer) in your comment is a great one and quite relevant for a 2017 model, specifically referenced in the question. The BB shell internal structure definitely needs to be assessed before one can confirm the FSA BB30 to BSA threaded can work.
